# Why Isn't keyframes smooth?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

So I am trying to get the text to flicker, but I would like there to be a smooth transition between keyframes. How would I do that?

```css
fire{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(yellow, orange,red);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation-name: fire;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes fire {
  0% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(yellow, orange, red);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  20% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow, orange);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  40% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, orange, orange);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  60% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(orange, yellow, red);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  80% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(yellow, orange, red);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  80% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, orange, red);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<fire>Flicker Flicker</fire>
```

What do you recommend I do to make the transitions smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Add `animation-timing-function: linear;` the default animation-timing-function is `ease` which will be a rougher animation.

```css
fire{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(yellow, orange,red);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation-name: fire;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes fire {
  0% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(yellow, orange, red);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  20% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow, orange);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  40% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, orange, orange);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  60% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(orange, yellow, red);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  80% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(yellow, orange, red);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, orange, red);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<fire>Flicker Flicker</fire>
```